# How to wrap a label text which is added inside a grid column?

Tags: java, gwt, label, word-wrap

I am writing a following code in gwt

```
 Grid  grid=new Grid(1,2);
 Label label=new Label("LongTextInLabel");
 Label label1=new Label("LongTextInLabel1");
 grid.setWidget(0, 0, label));
 grid.setWidget(0, 1, label1);
 grid.setWidth("100%");
 label.setwidth("50%");
 label1.setwidth("50%");
```

I want to wrap a text in label if it is overflowing a label width. I tried assigning

```
label.setWordWrap(true);
```

but somehow it is not working. Also i tried assigning it through css . 
Any workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that with css, just set a class to the label you want to wrap the text and use the [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) and [text-overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) properties

```
grid.addStyleName("fixed")
label.addStyleName("wrap")

.fixed {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.wrap {
     white-space: nowrap; 
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding it in css , but still it is not giving expected result. Somehow , label width get extended to accommodate the text

Comment: ok.. the problem is with the the way I set label width i.e 50% . If I set it to some value , then it works fine. Any work around for this?

Comment: maybe setting the table layout should fix your problems, and don't set the label size to 50% because it means that fill half of the `td`. Edited my response